# Calculate the position of the button on the page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use this code to calculate the padding of a button on a page from the browser border.

```
        Dimension dm = new Dimension(1024,768);
        //Setting the current window to that dimension
        driver.manage().window().setSize(dm);

        // Click Login button to submit login form
        WebDriverWait loginButtonWebDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 4000);

        WebElement loginButtonWebElement = loginButtonWebDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("login")));

        int loginButtonX = loginButtonWebElement.getLocation().getX();
        int loginButtonY = loginButtonWebElement.getLocation().getY();
        int loginButtonWidth = loginButtonWebElement.getRect().getWidth();
        int loginButtonHeight = loginButtonWebElement.getRect().getHeight();
        System.out.println("Login Button is " + loginButtonX + " pixels from left border.");
        System.out.println("Login Button is " + (screenWidth - loginButtonX + loginButtonWidth) + " pixels from right border.");
        System.out.println("Login Button is " + loginButtonY + " pixels from top border.");
        System.out.println("Login Button is " + (screenHeight - loginButtonY + loginButtonHeight) + " pixels from bottom border.");

        // We need to check that the size is not less than 10 pixels. If the space is less trow exception and fail the test.
        assertThat(loginButtonX).isGreaterThan(5);
        assertThat(loginButtonY).isGreaterThan(5);
```

The question is how to calculate that the Log in button is bound to the bottom right of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a `coordinate system` as:

```
  y ^
    |
    |              _
    |             |_|
    |---------------->
    (0,0)           x
```

You need to do if

```
(window_width - loginButtonWidth) < loginButtonX < window_width
```

and

```
0 < `loginButtonY` < loginButtonHeight.
```

Then it is on the bottom right of the screen.

You might need to add some padding if the button is not strictly on the corner.

Comment: What about left? How I can verify that it's on the left side?

Comment: left bottom corner? you need to change to 0  < loginButtonX < loginButtonWidth the other one remains the same

Comment: I added the code that I tested but I don't have a exception.

Comment: you are missing the heigh part there

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65189655/calculate-the-position-of-the-button-on-login-page